# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I always get the `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1` exception in the code below. Please advice what is wrong.

```
public boolean Foo(String str) {

        Cursor c = dbHelper.getItemByTitle(str);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            c.getString(1) // Irrespective of what argument put here I get this exception
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you instantiating your DB and opening it via `.open()` prior to this function being called?

Comment: What happens when you use the c.moveToFirst() or the c.moveToNext() function inside an if statement like the two answers demonstrate?  Does it return true or false?

Comment: I've also gotten this error as well "Index -1 requested, with a size of 1", and the resolution was as Jon Skeet said below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7391243/26510

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used Sqlite, but I suspect you need to call [`moveToNext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29) to get to the first row before asking for values:

```
if (!c.moveToNext()) {
    return false;
}
String value = c.getString(1);
...
```

Note that `getCount()` returns the number of *rows* in the result set, but the argument to `getString()` indicates the *column* number. Also note that as far as I can see from the docs, the column number here is zero-based, unlike JDBC which is one-based.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `c.moveToFirst()` to check if there is data in the query you are returning like so:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) 
      return true;
else
      return false;
```