# select one cell from sql database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying a simple SQL Command wihtin my Android-App, to get the age of a selected Person:

```
public int getAge(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name =? " + MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString(), null);
    int age = cursor.getInt(3);               // column with ages
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return age;
}
```

But when I run my app, it crashes when I call the function getAge(). I get the following Error:

```
SQLiteException: no such column: Max: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = Max
```

I don't get it. There is the name "Max" in the table. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit 2:
With this one:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE name = '" + MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString() + "'", null);
```

I get a different error:

```
08-27 19:43:47.573: E/AndroidRuntime(6161): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

what does this mean?

Comment: I updated my answer for this error. Also check what column you are selecting `"SELECT name FROM ..."`, you want to return the age not the name. You already know the name. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the `selectionArgs` parameter of `rawQuery()` to prevent [SQL Injection Attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = ?", new String[] { MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString() });
```

Also you only need *one* column so rather than wasting resources by selecting them all with `*`, you should just select the one column:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT age FROM persons WHERE name = ?", new String[] { MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString() });
```

Hope that helps!

---

All together it should look like:

```
public int getAge(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT age FROM persons WHERE name = ?", new String[] { MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString() });

    int age;
    // Check if you have a valid result and move to the first row to read it
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        age = cursor.getInt(0);
    // Prevent a crash if there is no data for this name
    else
        age = 0;

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return age;
}
```

Comment: was sitting half a week on this problem. works now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Chan ge the 3rd line of your program:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name =? " + MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString(), null);
```

to this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = ?",  new String[] { MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString()} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int getAge(){
    int age;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = '" + MainActivity.selectedPerson.getText().toString()+"'",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
    age = cursor.getInt(3);              // column with ages
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return age;
}
```

You missed the single quotes (' ') in your sql command. That's why MAX was taken as a column and not as a value.

Comment: thanks. I changed it and added the quotes (''), but now I'm getting the following error: 08-27 19:23:44.212: E/AndroidRuntime(29853): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: the one here. I edited the question again. srry for the mistake.

Comment: how many columns do you have in you table and what are they..?

Comment: For the reason of error check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391235/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-1-requested-with-a-siz