# SELECT entry in SQLite, without a WHERE condition?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I followed advice [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146267/select-one-cell-from-sql-database), but for my purposes I don't want a `WHERE`.

I don't know the value, so I cannot say `rawQuery("... WHERE x = ?", y)`, I don't care what `y` is, it's just a cell I want, and it is known that there is a single row.

If it is not possible to lose the condition (perhaps because of causing an indeterminate number of results?) - then how can I say "from column z and row 0"?

I'm lacking either terminology, or outright understanding, because my searches are turning up nothing.

***Edit:*** Eclipse doesn't complain at:

```
result = db.rawQuery("SELECT col FROM tbl", my_unused_string_array);
```

I'm not at a testing stage yet, and I can't enter this into the SQL db reader I was using to test `SELECT col FROM tbl` and ~ with `WHERE`.. will it work?

Comment: normally select* from tablename returns all the rows of a table.. as your table contains only one row, i think it will do work for your

Comment: @StinePike sorry I think your sentence got cut short, else I just don't understand what you mean

Comment: @StinePike I'm not doing `SELECT *` - that would be all columns. I only want one column, but all/the only row.

Comment: @TechAgent `WHERE TRUE` returns nothing, neither does `WHERE *`.

Comment: You can just use `null` for second parameter.

Comment: @AndrewT. I was using `null` before I came to stack. Eclipse gave me an error for it, because it wasn't type `String[]`.

Comment: I agree with @StinePike , if there's only one row in your table, `select col from tbl` will suffice. You can add a limit condition of 1 if you like: `select col from tbl limit 1`, but it won't change your results if you've only got one item in the table.

Comment: @JustinJasmann The whole premise of my question was *how* to do that. The function requires a second parameter to match `WHERE x = ?`, hence my issue. I *think* it's resolved as of my edit though.

Comment: Weird. I usually use `db.query()` and I can put `null` for `selectionArgs`. The equivalent for your query is `db.query("tbl",new String[]{"col"},null,null,null,null,null)`. But I am still confused since `null` is valid for `String[]` and Eclipse didn't gave me an error that it wasn't type `String[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your edit, you don't need to specify `WHERE` clause, if you want to get all the records from a table:

```
result = db.rawQuery("SELECT col FROM tbl", new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query "SELECT * FROM table" will return the entire table.  "SELECT colX, colY FROM table" will return columns colX and colY for all the rows in the table.  If your table contains just one row, "SELECT col FROM table" will return the value of col for that one row.

To use the SQLiteDatabase API to make that query, you would say:

```
result = db.rawQuery("SELECT col FROM tbl", null);
```

... because you are not supplying any query parameters.

Assuming that there is just one row seems dangerous to me.  I would **not** use the "LIMIT" clause, because, while that will always get one row, it will hide the fact that there is more than one row, if that happens.  Instead, I suggest that you assert that the cursor contains one row, like this:

```
if (1 != result.getCount()) {
    throw Exception("something's busted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Raw query use

```
Cursor cur = db.query(Table_name, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);
```

and get the desired attributes from cursor.

where the query method has parameters in following manner:

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

**Parameters:**

**table**  The table name to compile the query against.

**columns**  A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.

**selection**  A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

**selectionArgs**  You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.

**groupBy**  A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null will cause the rows to not be grouped.

**having**  A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor, if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING clause (excluding the HAVING itself). 
Passing null will cause all row groups to be included, and is required when row grouping is not being used.

**orderBy**  How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order, which may be unordered.

**Returns**
A **Cursor** object, which is positioned before the first entry.

Comment: I began using `rawQuery` to address the issue discussed with @AndrewT in OP comments - Eclipse didn't like me using `null` for all those args.

Comment: whether you happen to use query() or rawQuery() is pretty much irrelevant, as you surmise.  If eclipse is giving you an error when you use null as an argument, you should post that error:  null is a completely valid argument.